# Returning Action in override Create / Write method in ODOO

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-10

guys.

I have a case that confusing me.

I want to show a view when i click the save button.

I already tried these code. The Console / Terminal successfull print the message.
Thanks For Your Help. Regards

```
@api.multi
def write(self, vals):
    super(Project_Requisition_Inherit_Mpd, self).write(vals)
    print "Tipe Jasa Project Requisition Berhasl Diganti"
    return {
        'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
        'res_model': 'wizard.confirm.delete.project.req',
        'view_type': 'form',
        'view_mode': 'form',
        'target': 'new'
    }
```

Comment: I think that is not possible, and if it is possible you will break the ORM ;-)

Comment: It's just not possible. The write method doesn't want a dict with UI action . Only boolean.